# Write Output into File while being in a PS-Session

Tags: powershell

im trying to save the output from a pile of code into a cetrain text file, the problem is that the code is executed inside an PS-Session. Because of that im trying to use a global variable to save the output and later save it into the textfile after i terminate the connection, but i just cant get it to work. The output gets saved into the variable, i tried all kinds of global variables  but when i terminate the connection it just says the variable is null.
PS: Im very new to Powershell so dont be suprised about dumb mistakes

```
$global:temp = null
$path = "some path"
Invoke-Command -Computername server01 -Scriptblock {

$temp = some code |Out-String
Write-Host $temp  <--(Works fine)

}
$temp |Add-Content $path <--(Does not work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you'd like to:

```
$output = Invoke-Command -Computername server01 -Scriptblock { Some code }

$output | out-file $path -append
```

So the problem is that you are putting it into variable within the scriptblock.
In case if you've got more Servers in scope, I would recommend jobs.